# AWS DynamoDb fails when accessed from EC2 instance with Spring data

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-ec2, spring-data, amazon-dynamodb

Hy guys, when I run my Spring Boot 2 project from my local machine (Ubuntu) is all fine but 
when I tried to access DynamoDb tables from my Spring Boot 2 project running on EC 2 instance I received this error:

```
"The security token included in the request is invalid. (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: UnrecognizedClientException; Request ID: E0JP23I9DK11PE64OQV5MNLGR3VV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)"
```

After compiling my project I run it (on EC2 or my local machine) with the command line :

```
java -Daws.accessKeyId=... -Daws.secretKey=... -jar myApp.jar
```

To login into DynamoDB my code is :

```
@Configuration
@EnableDynamoDBRepositories(basePackages = "app.repositories")
public class DynamoDBConfig {

    @Autowired
    private ConfigProperties config;

    @Bean
    public AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB() {
        AWSCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = buildCredentials();
        AmazonDynamoDBClient.builder().withCredentials(credentialsProvider).withRegion("");
        return AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.defaultClient();
    }

    private AWSCredentialsProvider buildCredentials() {
        AWSCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new AWSCredentialsProvider(){

            @Override
            public AWSCredentials getCredentials() {
                return new BasicAWSCredentials(config.getAwsAccessKey(), config.getAwsSecretKey());
            }

            @Override
            public void refresh() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        };
        return credentialsProvider;
    }

}
```

To access tables I use this code :

```
@Getter
@Setter
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "user")
public class UserModel {

    @DynamoDBHashKey
    @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey   
    private String id;

    @DynamoDBIndexHashKey(globalSecondaryIndexName = "idx_global_userMatricula")
    @DynamoDBAttribute  
    private String matricula;

    @DynamoDBAttribute
    private String nome;

    @DynamoDBAttribute
    private String senha;

    @DynamoDBIndexHashKey(globalSecondaryIndexName = "idx_global_userClinicaId")
    @DynamoDBAttribute
    private String clinicaId;

    @DynamoDBAttribute
    private boolean active;

    @DynamoDBAttribute
    private boolean grantCli;

    @DynamoDBAttribute
    private boolean grantUser;

    @DynamoDBAttribute
    private String collection;

}
```

And my repository class is :

```
@EnableScan
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<UserModel,String>{

}
```

Tks ...

Comment: Looks like you may not be specifying a region if I am reading your code correctly. On your local box do you have a default region set in your config where on the EC2 instance you do not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a great practice to implement your own credentials provider.  I am assuming that the issue is whatever custom way you are getting your credentials on your local machine is not setup on the EC2 instance.

I would recommend to use the [DefaultCredentialsProvider](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/auth/credentials/DefaultCredentialsProvider.html) which goes through 5 different methods for finding credentials (see documentation).

Some of those methods work well on your local machine for testing such as environment variables as well as the the `~/.aws/credentials` file that is setup when you run the `aws configure` command locally.

Some of the methods are more ideal for EC2 instances like using the instance profile IAM Role associated with the EC2 instance.

Using the DefaultCredentialsProvider will allow you to use these different mechanisms without having to have different credentials providers for local vs EC2 deployments.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to assign a role to your EC2 instance in the AWS. Then use the DefaultCredentialsProvider as below

```
@Configuration
class DynamoConfig {

/**
 * Connects to a remote dynamo db instance.
 */
@Bean
fun getDynamoDbClient(): DynamoDbClient? {

    val credentialsProvider: AwsCredentialsProvider = DefaultCredentialsProvider.create()

    return DynamoDbClient.builder()
        .region(Region.EU_CENTRAL_1)
        .credentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).build()
}

@Bean
fun getDynamoDbEnhancedClient(): DynamoDbEnhancedClient {
    return DynamoDbEnhancedClient.builder()
        .dynamoDbClient(getDynamoDbClient())
        .build()
  }
}
```